# The IControllerFactory 'xxx.WindsorInstallerBase+WindsorControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name '~'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

I have the following error "The IControllerFactory 'xxx.WindsorInstallerBase+WindsorControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name '~'.". I was able to get that error when I implemented the error handler. Although that error is not fatal because our web application is still running but it keeps on saving on our error logs. I don't know where to find or what the cause of that error. Please if anybody encountered it or familiar with it please help. What is the cause of this error and what is the solution just in case?

Here's the StackTrace**

> **at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_2()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) 
>   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1
>   func)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing somewhere in your code you will have a tilde ~ not marked up correctly in your .cshtml files.

Maybe go through all .cshtml files looking for the link?

Comment: Thanks yes indeed. It's the favicon in my _Layout.cshtm